# How to retrieve deleted / Coulmns Rows records in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on below Data Frame. I deleted Column and I want to retrieve data as below.

```
print("\n Drop Column by Name \n")
data1.drop('Rank', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(data1) 

#Data before deleting column
Drop Column by Name 

     Age    Area  Gender  Marks Name     Price
0    NaN  1200.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  567890.0
1    NaN  1000.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  234567.0
2    NaN  1500.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  678950.0
3    NaN  3000.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  234765.0
4    NaN  4500.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  908675.0
5    NaN  2300.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  327865.0
6    NaN  1256.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  897887.0
7    NaN  1100.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  987767.0
8    NaN  1026.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  998799.0
9    NaN  2789.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  675889.0
10   NaN  2560.0     NaN    NaN  NaN  546556.0
0   22.0     NaN    Male   88.0    A       NaN
1   27.0     NaN  Female   87.0    B       NaN
2   25.0     NaN    Male   65.0    C       NaN
3   21.0     NaN    Male   45.0    D       NaN
4   28.0     NaN  Female   87.0    E       NaN
5   23.0     NaN  Female   69.0    F       NaN
6   22.0     NaN    Male   92.0    G       NaN
7   27.0     NaN    Male   74.0    H       NaN
8   25.0     NaN  Female   58.0    I       NaN
9   24.0     NaN  Female   76.0   J        NaN
10  27.0     NaN    Male   88.0    K       NaN
```

## After Deleting Column

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: You'r question is not understanble. Please consider editing it

Answer (score 0):

```
data1.drop('Rank', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Above line states that you have dropped column 'Rank'

`axis`: Based on the value 0 or 1 python will look for that label, In your case It will look in columns.

And important thing is you have set the `inplace=True`, this means you have permanently updated the dataframe. and its just an object.

clear all the session and re-execute the python file and this time before executing the python file make sure you are not setting `inplace=True`

could you please provide more code snippet, that will be help full to explain in brief.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can terminate the deleting statement.

To delete the column you can try below code:

```
df.drop(['Rank'], axis=1, inplace = True)
```

Also, I will suggest replacing "df" with variable name where you want to perform this

Answer (score 0):

I think python don't have any inbuilt function to retrieve deleted/dropped columns in pandas.
But to retrieve deleted index we can do as follows:
`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)`